# Cannot ping own ip from its linux network namespace

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

```
 ┌─────────┐     ┌─────────┐
 │   nsa   │     │   nsb   │
 │     ┌───┤     ├───┐     │
 │     │ifa├─────┤ifb│     │
 │     └───┤     ├───┘     │
 │         │     │         │
 └─────────┘     └─────────┘
 ifa = 192.168.43.71/24
 ifb = 192.168.43.72/24
```

The setup script below:

- connects two namespaces (`nsa` and `nsb`)
- via peer interfaces (`ifa` and `ifb`)
- within the same IP network (`192.168.43.0/24`).

Question:

- If I can cross-ping `ifb` from `nsa` and `ifa` from `nsb`:

````
```bash
# succeeds:
sudo ip netns exec nsa ping 192.168.43.72    # nsa -> ifb
sudo ip netns exec nsb ping 192.168.43.71    # nsb -> ifa
```
````

- **Why cannot I direct-ping `ifa` from `nsa` and `ifb` from `nsb`?**

````
```bash
# fails (timeout):
sudo ip netns exec nsa ping 192.168.43.71    # nsa -> ifa
sudo ip netns exec nsb ping 192.168.43.72    # nsb -> ifb
```
````

---

Copy-and-paste-able setup script:

```bash
# create namespaces:
sudo ip netns add nsa
sudo ip netns add nsb

# create peer interfaces:
sudo ip link add ifa type veth peer name ifb

# assign peer interfaces to their namespaces:
sudo ip link set ifa netns nsa
sudo ip link set ifb netns nsb

# assign addresses:
sudo ip -n nsa addr add 192.168.43.71/24 dev ifa
sudo ip -n nsb addr add 192.168.43.72/24 dev ifb

# bring up:
sudo ip -n nsa link set ifa up
sudo ip -n nsb link set ifb up
```

---

**DETAILS: troubleshoting info**

**`nsa`:**

```
sudo ip -n nsa addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
38: ifa@if37: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:45:ed:0d:00:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns nsb
    inet 192.168.43.71/24 scope global ifa
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9845:edff:fe0d:d7/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

sudo ip -n nsa route
192.168.43.0/24 dev ifa proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.71
```

**`nsb`:**

```
sudo ip -n nsb addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
37: ifb@if38: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:ca:5b:72:e0:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns nsa
    inet 192.168.43.72/24 scope global ifb
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::fcca:5bff:fe72:e04c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

sudo ip -n nsb route
192.168.43.0/24 dev ifb proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.72
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
sudo ip -n nsa link set lo up
sudo ip -n nsb link set lo up
```

---

Note that the `ping`-s in the question above were **not** directed to loopback.

Nevertheless, if loopback interface is down, the ping to itself on other intefaces does not work either!

The loopback interface `lo` is created automatically with the network namespace but remains down by default. It is not obvious that pining any other local IP address on other network interfaces requires `lo` to be up (even without assigning any loopback IP address e.g. `127.0.0.1/8`).

**Let me know if there is any official doc or spec showing why this is so.**

Comment: The loopback interface is used for local traffic. You don't involve a NIC (even if it's virtual) for traffic from the node to itself. Try this: `ip -n nsa route get 192.168.43.71` => `local 192.168.43.71 dev lo src 192.168.43.71 uid 0 
    cache <local>` even if lo is down (but then traffic doesn't work of course).